# Running dotMemory from Command Line

Tags: resharper, jetbrains-ide

Are there ways to run dotMemory directly from the command lines with argument? I've used both dotCover and dotTrace, and they have very different implementations for the achieving this (dotCover is directly from the command line, while dotTrace needs a generated xml config). I have seen the dotMemoryUnit, but it does not seem to accept additional arguments, nor have I found any other information about how to do this.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @Ed.ward We're want to dotMemory directly from the command lines with arguments, since we're trying to automate some of the analysis over night.

Comment: Do you want run dotMemory that will start a profiling session, or do you want get memory snapshots at some time points or may be something else?

Comment: @Ed.ward We have tests that will run and shut down the program. From the run in visual studio it seems the profiling will be done once the program is finished, and it can be exported to a nice workspace file. That's the thing we're looking for, in that it will run from the command line, start then finish the tests, and in the end we'll get a workspace file saved somewhere. We did this with dotTrace, but no luck with dotMemory. Edit: the argument part has to do with starting our tests.

Comment: I answered your question, but still not understand how and at what points you are going to get memory snapshots. If you provide more information, I would describe how to achieve, what you need, more detailed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**dotMemory Unit**

If you run tests, dotMemory Unit may be more suitable for your needs. Run dotMemoryUnit.exe -targetExecutable="your application which run tests" and your app will be started under the profiler. More details about doMemoryUnit.exe command line arguments you can find [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotmemory-unit/2.2/Using_dotMemory_Unit_Standalone_Runner.html).

In your test you can call dotMemoryApi.SaveCollectedData method, it will save a workspace contains all data from **one** test, but will not save anything if there are no memory snapshots were gotten.

**Standalone dotMemory**

There is a workaround for dotMemory. If you run dotMemory.exe /p:path_to_xml_configuration.xml it will start and run profiling automatically. **Note**: that dotMemory will delete the file passed in /p key, so make copy of it.
You are familiar with dotTrace xml configuration, so you need create almost the same configuration but replace

```
<Info type="PerformanceInfo">
```

node with this one

```
<Info type="MemoryInfo">
  <CollectAllocations>...</CollectAllocations>
</Info>
```

CollectAllocations value can be EnabledPostponed - dotMemory will not start collecting allocations data immediately but it's possible to turn on it later manually or via profiling API. Or EnabledImmediatly (yes, with typo) - will collect allocations data from the beginning if run in manual (not in Profiling API) mode.

**[EDIT]**

**dotMemory Command Line Tools**

New free tool allows getting snapshots using command line

```
dotMemory.exe get-snapshot MyApp --save-to-dir=C:\Snapshots
```

read this blog post for details 
https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/05/16/dotmemory-command-line-tools/

Comment: @ivanov dotMemory console runner is released with v. 2017.1https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/05/16/dotmemory-command-line-tools/